# ASP.Net MVC & Comet (WebSync)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, comet, http-post, websync

I'm trying to implement comet in my ASP.Net MVC 2.0 project. I'm using [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) from FrozenMountain. My website is coded in C# 4.0 and ASP.Net 4.0.

The comet code is triggering my MVC controller function with the [HttpPost] attribute (even though the page doesn't refresh or appear to post). Is there a way to determine what is being posted and ignore that route in my `global.asax.cs`?

- Please note, I know how to ignore routes with MVC, that is not the issue.

Comment: can you post some sample code?

Comment: Does WebSync really require log4net?  I'd like to explore using WebSync but I'm turned off by the apparent dependency.  It's not listed as a requirement, but it is included in the download and the tutorial mentions it.

Comment: @uosef - I'd recommend contacting Jared at Frozen Mountain. He was very helpful with providing us with technical details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gentlemen at Frozen Mountain helped me solve the problem [here](http://groups.google.com/group/websync/browse_thread/thread/b173f2bf617f1ff0)

It was hitting one of my MVC controller functions. I had to add this to my global.asax.cs

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allashx}", new {allashx=@".*\.ashx(/.*)?"});
```

Comment: For future reference, our docs now include this detail: http://docs.frozenmountain.com/#class=server-troubleshooting-asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

In WebSync 4, you can skip the .ashx handler altogether and just add a route for WebSync directly in Global.asax:

```
WebSyncServer.AddRoute("...");
```