# facebook like Notificaton system in mvc2.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, comet

i m developing an application in asp.net 3.5 using mvc2. i want to implement facebook like notification system based on server push or comet. i have no idea where and what to start with. i have read about Pokein but don't know how to integrate it with mvc. any suggestions are held highly

thanks 
Adeel

Comment: There are several sample projects available at project web site (http://pokein.codeplex.com) and once you learn how it is working you can implement it onto every kind of ASP.NET & Mono projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are sample MVC projects for PokeIn library ([visit here](http://pokein.codeplex.com)). On the other hand, PokeIn is a good choice in comparison to other alternatives. (License costs, event ordering, disconnection detection, "reverse ajax" support etc)..

Also, you may need to check the documentation for PokeIn [here](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a comet framework for .NET. Easy to use, lots of examples...should do what you want.

See also:
[ASP.Net MVC & Comet (WebSync)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241246/asp-net-mvc-comet-websync)

Comment: thanks javenema,
websync is great as folks say but i m interested in some open source solution

Comment: also i have come across pokein but there is no example illustrating how it can be used with MVC. if anyone knows plz let me know
regards

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Can't help you there :(.